# Finding contours and midpoints of color squares in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have an image with color squares in it:

[image: Image of the squares]

I am trying find contours for the color squares, as well as the midpoints of the color squares to find the pixel value.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am able to find this strip I mean contour as whole strip. But stuck in finding the contours for the squares

Comment: If they are evenly space and sized, you could just offset to the first square and then just crop at equal intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HSV colour space`, but you have to pick a range of colour by hand.

change the `H` value based on colour and keep the entire range of `0-255` for both `S` and `V` or you can limit these as well to be more specific.

Then you can use contours to draw a bounding box around the detected contour and find the centre.

Here's the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('UQjNf.jpg')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

bi = np.zeros((hsv.shape[:2]),np.uint8)

bi[np.where((((hsv <= [20,255,255]) & (hsv >= [20,0,0])) | (hsv <= [21,255,255]) & (hsv >= [21,0,0]) | ((hsv <= [22,255,255]) & (hsv >= [22,0,0])) ).all(axis = 2))] = [255]

plt.imshow(bi)
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
plt.show()
```

Here's one such colour that came out nicely
[image]

Hope it helps.